# EntityFramework in test initialization error: CREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to build a quick test that deletes and recreates a database every time it runs.  I have the following:

```
[TestClass]
public class PocoTest
{
    private TransactionScope _transactionScope;
    private ProjectDataSource _dataSource; 
    private Repository _repository = new Repository();
    private const string _cstring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=test_db;Trusted_Connection=True";

    [TestInitialize]
    public virtual void TestInitialize()
    {
        _dataSource = new ProjectDataSource(_cstring);
        _dataSource.Database.Delete();
        _dataSource.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
        _transactionScope = new TransactionScope();
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestBasicOperations()
    {                
        var item = _repository.AddItem(new Item(){Details = "Test Item"});
        //  AddItem makes a call through the data context to add a set and then calls datacontext.SaveChanges()
    }


    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        // rollback
        if (_transactionScope != null)
        {
            _transactionScope.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

However when I run the test I get the following error:

> Result Message:    Test method
>   Project.Repository.UnitTests.PocoTest.TestBasicOperations threw
>   exception:  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: CREATE DATABASE
>   statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction.

ProjectDataSource is here:

```
public class ProjectDataSource : DbContext, IProjectDataSource
{

    public ProjectDataSource() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    public ProjectDataSource(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Set> Sets { get; set; }
}
```

Repository:

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private readonly ProjectDataSource _db = new ProjectDataSource();
    public Item AddItem(Item item)
        {
            _db.Items.Add(item);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return item;
        }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Also - if it makes any difference - the error doesn't occur if I comment out the AddItem line in TestMethod.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this issue:

In my Repository class, I have another definition of what's commonly labeled a "dbContext" - ProjectDataSource.  This means that one context was created in my test class, while another was created in my Repository object.  Sending the connectionstring to my repo class solved the problem:

In Repository:

```
public class Repository : IRepository
    {
        private readonly ProjectDataSource _db;

        public Repository(string connectionString)
        {
            _db = new ProjectDataSource(connectionString);   
        }

        public Repository()
        {
            _db = new ProjectDataSource();   
        }
```

From my test:

```
private TransactionScope _transactionScope;
        private Repository _repository;
        private ProjectDataSource _dataSource; 
        private const string _connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=test_db;Trusted_Connection=True";

        [TestInitialize]
        public virtual void TestInitialize()
        {
            _repository = new Repository(_connectionString);
            _dataSource = new ProjectDataSource(_connectionString);
            _dataSource.Database.Delete();
            _dataSource.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
            _transactionScope = new TransactionScope();
        }
```

Comment: I don't completely understand why this problem is caused. 
Are you saying that creating 2 equivalent dbcontext instance causes the problem. meaning that only one dbcontext to a specific db can exist in the application ?

Comment: Eran Otzap, I know it is a litle late, but having faced this issue today, I thought it would be helpfull to publish an answer explaining the root causes. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, sqlCommand);`

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24344654/375114 for details

Answer (score 5):

For your information, this error occurs by design and it happens whenever *non-transactionable* commands are issued to **Microsoft SQL Server** within an active transaction.

The solution is, therefore, granting that **Database.CreateIfNotExists()** hits the database out of any transaction scope. Remember, **SQL Profiler** is your friend.

You can get a roughly [updated list of commands that are not allowed to run whithin transactions](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00729.1500/html/errMessageAdvRes/BABFDFIB.htm).

Note: In case one wonders why am I providing a list based on a Sybase's product, bear in mind that Microsoft SQL Server shares most of its basic genetic with Sybase' engine. For further reading, refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server

Comment: This answer addresses the title of the question but not the body of the question. Yes, the question’s title is misleading and results in this being a top Google hit for the question you answered, but this question isn’t that question x.x. Waaah

Answer (score 3):

You can not use implicit commits around certain SQL commands.
Creating and Deleting databases is an example
SQL server will do an **AUTOCommit**

See the remarks section in the MS SQL help.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx

and something on Auto Commit for more info...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187878%28v=sql.105%29

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))

{
 var sqlCommand = String.Format("Create DATABASE [{0}]", "TempBackupDB");
                             _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, sqlCommand);

ts.Complete();

}

Comment: Only creates an empty database. Then what?

Answer (score -1):

You need to run **Update-Database** command on package manager console.

Comment: How would you do that in a unit test method?