# Alter Database in Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework

I have update my EF to EF 6.0.2 in my code I have the following line of code:

```
 applicationDbContext.Database .ExecuteSqlCommand(@"ALTER DATABASE
 CURRENT SET RECOVERY FULL;");
```

After updating I get the following error message:

> ALTER DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement
>   transaction.

I have fixed the problem with a TransctionalBehavior like the the code below:

```
applicationDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, @"ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET RECOVERY FULL;");
```

My question:

- Why I'm getting this error with EF 6?
- My fix is a valid fix for the problem or a devil hiding behind this solution?
- Is there any other approach to solve the problem?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!?

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution, that was my exact issue as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

EF 6 changes the use of transactions with ExecuteSqlCommand

> Starting with Entity Framework 6.0, ExecuteSqlCommand() by default will wrap the command in a transaction if one was not already present. There are overloads of this method that allow you to override this behavior if you wish.

EF 5 did not behave the same way.  Your fix is appropriate.

> You can now specify a TransactionalBehavior flag to instruct EF on how to handle transactions with this command.

```
var sqlCommand = String.Format("ALTER DATABASE {0} SET SINGLE_USER 
                                WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE");
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, 
                              sqlCommand);
```

By using the DoNotEnsureTransaction flag, EF will not start a transaction before executing the command. This allows the ALTER DATABASE command to successfully execute.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Code First approach possible solution is

```
public partial class AlterDatabase : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {                                           
        Sql("ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET RECOVERY FULL", true);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 from me because you are a new in SO and not for the answer ;-) the problem 1) wasnt in the migration 2) it was from the nested transactions.  I know that the code above will works but when you put it in the nested transactions it will cause the same problem.